# I'm not able to split my code into functions

Tags: python

I made a code to download pdfs from a website, and it works perfectly, downloading all the PDF's (first code below). However, when I split my code into functions, only two links are inserted into the "papers" list and the execution ends with code zero, but the following warning message appears:

```
GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.
The code that caused this warning is on line 11 of the file C:\Downloads\EditoraCL\download_pdf.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.
   for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
```

FIRST CODE:

```
import requests
import httplib2
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

papers = []
pdfs = []
http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/site/anais')
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        papers.append(link['href'])
        print(papers)

for x in papers:
    if x.endswith('pdf'):
        pdfs.append(x)
    print(pdfs)


def baixa_arquivo(url, endereco):
    resposta = requests.get(url)
    if resposta.status_code == requests.codes.OK:
        with open(endereco, 'wb') as novo_arquivo:
            novo_arquivo.write(resposta.content)
            print('Download concluído. Salvo em {}'.format(endereco))
    else:
        resposta.raise_for_status()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_basica = 'https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/{}'
    output = 'Download'
    for i in range(1, len(pdfs)):
        nome_do_arquivo = os.path.join(output, 'artigo{}.pdf'.format(i))
        a = pdfs[i]
        z = url_basica.format(a)
        y = requests.get(z)
        if y.status_code!=404:
            baixa_arquivo(z, nome_do_arquivo)
```

CODE DIVIDED INTO FUNCTIONS:

```
import requests
import httplib2
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
papers = []
pdfs = []
def busca_links():

    http = httplib2.Http()
    status, response = http.request('https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/site/anais')
    for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            papers.append(link['href'])
            return papers


def links_pdf():
    for x in papers:
        if x.endswith('pdf'):
            pdfs.append(x)
            return pdfs


def baixa_arquivo(url, endereco):
    resposta = requests.get(url)
    if resposta.status_code == requests.codes.OK:
        with open(endereco, 'wb') as novo_arquivo:
            novo_arquivo.write(resposta.content)
            return f'Download concluído. Salvo em {endereco}'
    else:
        resposta.raise_for_status()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    busca_links()
    links_pdf()
    url_basica = 'https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/{}'
    output = 'Download'
    print(papers)
    print(pdfs)
    for i in range(1, len(pdfs)):
        nome_do_arquivo = os.path.join(output, 'artigo{}.pdf'.format(i))
        a = pdfs[i]
        z = url_basica.format(a)
        y = requests.get(z)
        if y.status_code!=404:
            baixa_arquivo(z, nome_do_arquivo)
```

Could someone help me understand why the second code is giving this error?

Comment: One problem is that in both `busca_links()` and `links_pdf()`, your return statement is incorrectly indented. This will cause each function to return after the first match is found. Given that you don't actually use the return values, you could simply remove those return statements entirely. Or correct the indentation.

Comment: to add to @jarmod comment, if you do correct the indentations, you also need to start using the values, i.e. in your main write `papers = busca_links()`, otherwise, the return will go nowhere

Comment: Note that the warning should be present in both cases and is not related to not getting all results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions do not share their inner variables, so in order to make your code work, you should assign "papers" to the function itself, after returning it inside the function ( **papers** = busca_links() and links_pdf(**papers**) ).

Anyway, for the purpose of organization and clearer code, you should use classes and methods:

```
import os
import requests
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


class Pdf:

    def __init__(self, base_url, url):
        self.main_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.pdfs_dir = os.path.join(self.main_dir, 'pdfs')
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.url = url
        
    def get_links(self):
        http = httplib2.Http()
        status, response = http.request(self.url)
        self.links = []
        for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
            if link.has_attr('href'):
                if link['href'].endswith('pdf'):
                    self.links.append(f"{self.base_url}{link['href']}")

    def download_pdf(self):
        for link in self.links:
            response = requests.get(link, stream=True)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                file_path = os.path.join(self.pdfs_dir, link.split('/')[-1])
                with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                print('Success. Saved on {}'.format(file_path))
            else:
                # Should handle errors here, by appending them to a list and
                # trying again later.
                print('Error.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_url = 'https://www.snh2021.anpuh.org/'
    url = f'{base_url}site/anais'
    pdf = Pdf(base_url, url)
    pdf.get_links()
    pdf.download_pdf()
```